# WordPress error: Creation of dynamic property ... is deprecated

Tags: error, installation, deprecated

I have a brand new installation of WP+CiviCRM on a virtual private server. Every page loads with these errors at the top of the page:

```
Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property CiviCRM_For_WordPress_Admin::$menu_page 
is deprecated in /var/www/vhosts/my.domain.tld/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.admin.php on line 629

Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property CiviCRM_For_WordPress::$wp_get 
is deprecated in /var/www/vhosts/my.domain.tld/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php on line 1276

Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property CiviCRM_For_WordPress::$wp_post 
is deprecated in /var/www/vhosts/my.domain.tld/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php on line 1277

Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property CiviCRM_For_WordPress::$wp_cookie 
is deprecated in /var/www/vhosts/my.domain.tld/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php on line 1278

Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property CiviCRM_For_WordPress::$wp_request 
is deprecated in /var/www/vhosts/my.domain.tld/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php on line 1279
```

I believe this is merely a warning and not something I can fix; it would need to be fixed in the core code. So **how do I hide these errors?**

WordPress 6.4.1
CiviCRM 5.67.1
PHP 8.2.12

**EDIT:** I found that my VPS has **debugging turned on** and when I turn that off, these errors disappear. While that's an immediate way to hide these errors, this also means that *any other errors are also hidden.* Because of this implication, I'd like to find a way to turn this debugging on again but explicitly ignoring these particular errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those notices have [already been fixed](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-wordpress/pull/305) and the fix will be included in the upcoming 5.69 release.

Comment:  Thank you! I'm still working on what's where in regard to this software. There's a lot.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: I'm getting these same warning, and I'm using 5.71.1 version, I guess the 5.69 didn't fix them?